# ajax call can still be synchronous call, is that right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Although ajax is called “Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, but we can still call it synchronous, is that right?

using async: false

Comment: Yes. The command standard usage is asynchronous, but it doesn't have to be. I suppose then it just becomes JAX.

Comment: Most of the time people don't fetch XML these days, they just fetch 'stuff', so I guess that makes it SJAS.

Comment: Using synchronous AJAX (while possible) is usually a bad thing.  While it makes the programming simpler sometimes, it makes the user experience worse because the browser stops processing all user events while the synchronous ajax call is in progress.  To the user the page appears hung or locked during the ajax call.  Bad idea.  Learn how to write asynchronous javascript using callbacks and deferreds.

Comment: @ColinE, 'stuff' :P

AJAX -> Asynchronous javascript and xml
AJAX -> A-synchronous javascript and xml 

So, its AJAX in both contexts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is a general technique that is used for creating websites. In simplistic terms it allows you to dynamically update a page without a complete re-fresh by asynchronously retrieving data from the server. This data is then used to update the current page. This process is asynchronous, but you can choose to make it sycnhronous by waiting for the response.

If you are referring the the jQuery ajax function, yes you can make it synchronous using `async:false` as described in the manual:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) when used with `jqXHR($.Deferred)` as of jQuery 1.8.